# Excel Custom Filter with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter a Huge list of over 9000 rows.
Each row is an individual project and
all the rows are located in a table, "Table2";
the Sheet is "Final Data"

the lower bound is need to filter is "17-0034";
the Upper bound is "17-0152"

How do I filter between these lower & upper bound
Value is a text field.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Sheets("Final Data").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:= _
    Array("Active", "Completed", "Main"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:= _
    "RTB"

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    ">=17-0034", Operator:=x1And, Criteria2:="<=17-0152", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Please note that this question has been solved and the error was a syntax Typo of 1 vs l. I will leave the question to help those who are trying to understand how to create Custom Filters in VBA.

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

`x1And` is undefined. You could catch that easily, had you used `Option Explicit`.

Replace `x1And` this with `xlAnd` ('l' ell, not '1') and your filter will work fine.

Comment: I had actually used option Explicit, but I assumed it didn't like the values I was using. I did not think it was possible because of the text value

Comment: Would you know how to do the same operation but instead read the lower bound and upperbound off a cell? LBound:= A1; UBound:= A2 `Dim a, b As Variant a = Worksheets("Welcome").Cells(1, "A").Value b = Worksheets("Welcome").Cells(2, "A").Value ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _ >=a, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:= <= b, Operator:=xlFilterValues `

Comment: @DougthePug use `">=" & a` and `"<=" & b`